# How to send position using Telegram Desktop?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to move my first steps in Telegram, so sorry for the entry-level question.

I'm trying to use some simple Bot that I'd like to replicate and then evolve them: testing these bots from Telegram Desktop on my pc (Win7), I should send my position to obtain some response.

For example try to use **Farmacie Italiane** as bot .....

The bots suggest me to use the the bottom right icon (on the left of "Scrivi un messaggio" in the picture),

[image]

but when I click on it I can upload a file or a a photo.

How can I send my position to the bot?

Any suggestion is appreciate ... thank you in advance!!

Cesare

Comment: You can try to send the location with some inline bot.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Seems like Telegram for Windows doesn't allow to send location right now.
But you can use any mobile version for this.

UPDATE: as of May 2016 Telegram Desktop for Mac (v. 2.10.45.133) has this feature. The Linux desktop version has not this feature (v. 0.9.42).

Nov 2016: Windows desktop client (v. 0.10.19) still doesn't have this feature.

Feb 2017: Windows desktop client (v. 1.0.12) still doesn't have this feature.

Jun 2017: Windows desktop client (v. 1.1.7) still doesn't have this feature.

Jun 2018: Windows desktop client (v. 1.3.7 alpha) still doesn't have this feature.

Comment: v 2.3.1 for windows and still doesn't have this feature

Comment: Windows desctop client (v. 3.0.1) still dosn't have this feature :)

Comment: 08.12.22 still doesnt have this feature.

Comment: 09.03.2023 - fuсК windowz